# Google Maps v3 jquery mobile get center latitude and longitude

Tags: google-maps, jquery-mobile, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to draw markers on the map after a map has been initialised. However I need to know the central point lng lats.

I've tried using both of these however I'm getting "Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded" in chrome js;

```js
$('#map_canvas').gmap('get', 'map').getCenter()); and also 
$('#map_canvas').gmap('option', 'center');

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-ui-map-3.0-rc/ui/jquery.ui.map.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-ui-map-3.0-rc/ui/jquery.ui.map.extensions.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />

<script>
$('#map_page').live("pageshow", function() {
    function add_markers() {
        var location = $('#map_canvas').gmap('option', 'center');
    $.getJSON( 'http://localhost/motherly/android/index.php/api/venues?lat=' + location.lat() + '&lng=' + location.lng(), function(data) { 

        console.log(data['response']);

        $.each(data.response, function(i, marker) {
            // console.log(marker.lat, marker.lng);
            $('#map_canvas').gmap('addMarker', { 
                'position': new google.maps.LatLng(marker.lat, marker.lng), 
                'bounds': true 
            }).click(function() {
                $('#map_canvas').gmap('openInfoWindow', { 'content': marker.name }, this);
            });
        });
    }); 
    }

    function initialize(lat,lng) {
        $('#map_canvas').gmap({'center' : new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng), 'callback': function(){
            add_markers();
        }});
    }

    if(navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position){
            console.log(position);
            initialize(position.coords.latitude,position.coords.longitude);
            // google.maps.event
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apologies chaps I realised the issue was that I'm calling the draw method **inside** the constructor for the map which makes sense that the map object isn't initialised.

So to recap the issue is the add_markers() method being inside of this constructor (move the add_markers() below this line);

```
$('#map_canvas').gmap({'center' : new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng), 'callback': function(){

}});
```